# how to embed html5 into website via plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I’m trying to embed an html/javascript application into my website.
I do this my first time and bought an with a bit of description how to do it.
I thought it’s easier but I don’t get it to work.

That’s the tutorial that comes with the app:
https://support.vebto.com/help-center/articles/10/13/50/getting-started

What I did to embed it was creating a new plugin folder in FDP-Manager. And put all the Plugin-Files in it, like described.
And made a .php file, in which I defined a shortcode, so I can place the app wherever I want on my webpage.
Underneath I put the code, which they provide for embedding the plugin.
My code firist:

```php
 <?php
    /**
    * Plugin Name: My_first_embed
    * Plugin URI: http://www.my_first_embed.doesntmatter
    * Description: My_first_embed
    * Version: 1.0
    * Author: Me
    * Author URI:
    **/
    ?>
    add_shortcode( ‘shortcode_name’, function () {
    
    $out = ‘<p>[editor]</p>’;
    
    return $out;
    } );
    add_action( ‘wp_head’, function () { ?>
    <script>
    
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”pixie/styles.min.css”>
    </head>
    <body>
    <pixie-editor></pixie-editor>
    ​
    <script src=”pixie/scripts.min.js”></script>
    ​
    <script>
    var pixie = new Pixie({
    onLoad: function() {
    console.log(‘Pixie is ready’);
    }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

First, the plugin worked, but it was not loading, then I changed the code too because I thought that it should be enough... but it didn’t work either:

```
    <pixie-editor></pixie-editor>
    ​
    <script src=”pixie/scripts.min.js”></script>
    ​
    <script>
    var pixie = new Pixie({
    onLoad: function() {
    console.log(‘Pixie is ready’);
    }
    });
    </script>​
```

So any suggestions? 
I appreciate every contribution!

thank you!
cheers

Comment: Your quotes are weird. When I run `console.log(‘Pixie is ready’)` in my console, it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. That may be the problem. Try with normal `'` or double `"` quotes. Do you have any error in your console?

Comment: The quotes are not legal quotes in JavaScript - don't edit code in a word processor. Use a code editor instead. VS Code is free and supports PHP and JavaScript. Additionally, you have a dangling `<script>` tag that needs to be removed  just before the opening `<html>` tag.

Comment: i changed the quotes to normal and to single ones, actually the double ones are working. If i start the app in the browser it's working, just directly in the website it does not.
Yeah, i saw the script tag, after i published it here :)